# Laravel adding Gate with vendor:publish

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

So I am developing a composer package, that adds several of my reusable code to a fresh Laravel project. So far I've managed to add core translation files and some models, routes in my service provider with `$this->publishes()` and `$this->loadRoutesFrom()` in my `boot()` method.

Now I want to add Gates to that package, but I'm stuck. Somehow I should register these in the project's `AuthServiceProvider` on run. Would be very nice if anyone could give me some advice how to perform this task.

Comment: How is this related to Composer?

Comment: As I am building a composer package. But I give the point that it's more related to laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register policies, there is no need to use the AuthServiceProvider, you can simply use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::policy($key, $value)`.

You can do that in your own ServiceProvider of your package. If you want to define abilities, you can add a `boot` method like this:

```php
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;

    // ...

    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
            return $user->id === $post->user_id;
        });
    }
```

This will resolve the gate instance for you and allow you to define abilities. It's important to use the `boot` method, since this way you can be sure every service is already registered.